# T-SQL / SQL Server logical select

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is broken out into many rows. The table looks like the below:

Table `admissions`:

```
PersonID    Field_Value 
------------------------
  1775      UNDECIDED
  1775      PC-STJ
  1775      N/A
  1775      DEMENTIA
  1775      STJ
  1775      0
  1775      N/A
  1775      N/A
  1775      N
```

I to have a view that will capture the information on one line like the below.

Please note that the above is what it gives me in the database unlike the UI.

```
1775,  UNDECIDED, PC -STJ, N/A, DEMENTIA, STJ, 0, N/A, N/A, N
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How can I capture the information on 1 row? like 1775, UNDECIDED, PC -STJ, N/A, DEMENTIA, STJ, 0, N/A, N/A, N

Comment: Do you happen to have a simple example of Stuff and how I can use it?

Comment: Yes....@TabAlleman linked an excellent example of this technique. I am not sure how much simpler it could be. It is almost exactly the same thing you are doing. Unless one of us coded it for you it isn't going to be an easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Admission TABLE (PersonID INT, Field_Value VARCHAR(25));
INSERT INTO @Admission
    VALUES  (1775,'UNDECIDED'),
            (1775,'PC-STJ'),
            (1775,'N/A'),
            (1775,'DEMENTIA'),
            (1775,'STJ'),
            (1775,'0'),
            (1775,'N/A'),
            (1775,'N/A'),
            (1775,'N');

SELECT  PersonID,
        STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT ', ' + Field_Value
                    FROM @Admission
                    WHERE PersonID = A.PersonID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ),
        1,2,'') AS Field_Values
FROM @Admission A
GROUP BY PersonID
```

Results:

```
PersonID    Field_Values
----------- ------------------------------------------------------
1775        UNDECIDED, PC-STJ, N/A, DEMENTIA, STJ, 0, N/A, N/A, N
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    SELECT o.PersonID , fieldvalues = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + field_value 
          FROM admissions i
          where i.PersonID= o.PersonID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
         , 1, 1, '')
    from admissions o. Group by  o.PersonID ;
```

Comment: You missed group by person